# How would a civilization deal with Jupiter level gravity for colonization

Tags: planets, gravity, space-colonization

Consider the planets of the solar system. Each one is unique with its own unique problems when it comes to colonization. This question is specifically about one aspect of living on Jupiter. Based on other questions asked on this site by others I have discovered that up to 1.5 Gs could be handled for living on a planet if with increased mortality and a number of side effects. Jupiter is the only planet in the solar system with gravity above that range, approaching 2.5 Gs.The only body with higher gravity is the Sun. This is too high to permit unaided colonization as has been established. However what about aided colonization. Are there any hypothetical technologies that would permit people to survive Jupiter level gravity for living on the planet. If not what about for seasonal research trips as is done with Antarctica. I would prefer solutions that are modifications to the city not the people as the civilization I was asking for doesn't have genetic engineering and this vastly complicates mobility between planets. While it might be interesting to have a world where each planet is inhabited by a different subspecies that is not what I'm trying here. Alternate plans are being formulated for keeping the city in the planet's atmosphere not falling down. Unless a specific means is required for a plan don't worry about it. I have heard some people mention fluid support vaguely and want to know if there are any other options.Details about fluid support are somewhat annoying to find so far. For any options you post can you explain why it works as this civilization uses magitek primarily and I will probably have to convert it so a explanation as to how it works would be nice

Comment: What is the reason of this colonization, and tech level available?

Comment: Honestly, if surface gravity is such an issue I would probably recommend building a colony station in orbit instead. By adjusting it's spin you can set it to whatever comfortable gravity level you need. Plus by using drones and exo-suites you can still run your colony using local resources from the planet below.

Answer (score 0):

This was discussed in Mission of Gravity by Hal Clement where the planet has 3G of gravity at the equator. The way that the characters deal with gravity is to live in baths of breathable liquid which supported their body though hydraulic pressure countering the gravity. Characters communicated through the fluid with radios and such as it was written in the 50's. To walk around on the planet a powered exoskeleton was used to assist movement.

A spell could be used to make water breathable which people would use for rest and most likely everyone would wear a powered exoskeleton or something similar to amplify their strength and allow movement on the planet. Most of the issues for powered exoskeletons are actually solved with magitech so translation to higher gravity would not be as large of a issue as first conceived everything just needs to be more powerful per unit weight which will be more expensive.